# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Differential Forms. Conditions?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Let w be a k-form with compact suport in a k-manifold M ( say $\mathbb R^{k}$ to simplify, but I would appreciate generalizations to k-manifolds ) and define $F:= \int_{\gamma} w $, for $\gamma$ a k-submanifold .Under what conditions do we have : $df=w$? This seems equivalent to passinng the differential ( exterior derivative) from the outside-in, i.e., when can we say that $d \int_{\gamma} w= \int_{\gamma} dw$? I am pretty sure this has to see with Stoke's theorem and DeRham's theorem, and whether w is exact,  but not sure how. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: How is $F$ even a function to differentiate when you fix $\gamma$ to be a $k$-dimensional submanifold?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin :Can't we apply/use the exterior derivative dF  of F as defined? I know this can be done for 1-forms, cant't? If so, can't we extend the concept to higher dimensions?

Comment: Would this work in the case of 1-forms w?

Comment: It works for $1$-forms if $\gamma$ is a path from a fixed point to a variable point $x$ *and* $\omega$ is exact. (There's a question of well-definedness if $\omega$ is only closed.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks; could you please refer me to the theorems to use to show this?

Comment: It's in all sorts of books, but you might want to check out my [lectures on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd). In particular, see lecture 32 in MATH 3510. (But you might find other lectures of interest, as well.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks, will look you up. Could you please be more specific about the theorem(s) used in the meantime? My PC has no sound, so I will have to wait to be able to see your videos. Thanks again.

Comment: For that it's just the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thanks, Ted Shifrin.